# How to allow access to a file after passing from other file in apache?

Tags: html, apache, access-control

What I'm trying is that if someone logs into my website, I want the file configPage.html not to be accessible directly (from www.mydomain.com/configPage.html), but I want it to be accessible if had passed from login.html before.

I have to say that is my first web page so don't blame me if I'm trying something that makes no sense ;).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need some one to access your configPage.html then create a login page and then redirect to configPage.html. And if some one manually try to enter the file name  in the brower , you can check the session variable set or not . If not you can make page to redirect to your login page.